# Saving to DB works...but an error is thrown

Tags: javascript, php

Hello fellow programmers!

I'm fairly new to PHP/JavaScript and have to admit it is quite the learning experience, but I am enjoying it quite a bit.  I have a bit of a problem when I'm saving to a Database using Ajax however.  The save works perfectly fine, but instead of falling into my "success" code it falls into the "error" section and gives me a Status of 200.  I'm not sure what the status 200 means and am confused because it does actually save to the Database correctly.  Eventually what I want to do is use a JavaScript function to updated fields (when successfully saving to the DB), but right now I'm just trying to display a message to the user.  Also, in the JavaScript code I have to have the single quotes (') around the ajax variables (i.e. url, type, dataType, etc.) for it to work.  I've tried adding the single quotes around success and error and their associated functions to no avail.  Thanks!

Javascript:

```
function SaveUserBlankAnswer(form) {
    if (form.Answer.value != "") {
        var answer = form.Answer.value;
        var contentID = form.ContentID.value;
        var userID = form.UserID.value;

        $.ajax({
            'url': 'Database/SaveUserBlankAnswer_db.php',
            'type': 'POST',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'data': { ContentID: contentID, UserID: userID, Answer: answer },
            success: function(){
                alert('BOOSH!');
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert(data.status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("DBConnection.php");

$duplicateCheck = "SELECT UserID FROM BlankAnswer WHERE ContentID = " . $_POST[ContentID] . " AND UserID = " . $_POST[UserID];
if ($duplicateResult = $mysqli->query($duplicateCheck)) {
$rowCount = $duplicateResult->num_rows;

if ($rowCount == 0) {
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO BlankAnswer (UserID, ContentID, Answer)
            VALUES('$_POST[UserID]', '$_POST[ContentID]', '$_POST[Answer]');";
} else {
    $SQL = "UPDATE BlankAnswer SET Answer = '" . $_POST[Answer] . "' WHERE ContentID = '" . $_POST[ContentID] . "' AND UserID = '" . $_POST[UserID] . "'";
}
$mysqli->query($SQL);
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: [http-Status-Code (200)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.1)

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: whats the error that is throwing ??

Comment: Thank you aldanux, reading through the link makes me believe that 200 is actually a success message or OK at least.  But I'm confused, if thats the case why does the Ajax spill it into the "error:" portion of code instead of the "success:" portion of code?

Comment: Leo Bali: it simply says "200" for data.status.  Aldanux link has good information in it, but I'm still confused why it's considered an "error"?

Daniel - thanks for the heads up on the SQL injection attacks!  Like I said, I'm a TOTAL newb to this type of dev.  I'm usually quite happy living in the land of C#/ASP, so this is a bit of an adventure for me.  Can you offer some suggestion that might make it more secure?

Comment: try to use exit(); after you close the DB connection

Comment: Thanks Leo...unfortunately I get the same results even after adding exit();.  For PHP coding, is it proper to add the exit(); to each PHP file/function?

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery serialize method to create the form data for submission as you are not escaping the data on directly passing it.

Return 1 on success and 0 in failure from PHP script. No data is bad. Your POST request has no response, so maybe it thinks as an error. and the error in callback is for AJAX error. You can pass 0 or any message on DB level error.

```
function SaveUserBlankAnswer(form) {
//do validations here
    var formData = $('#formId').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Database/SaveUserBlankAnswer_db.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.status === "1") {
                //Show success
            } else if(data.status === "0") {
                // alert for error on saving to DB
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
         alert('AJAX ERROR');
         }
    });

}
```

Hope it helps

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Thanks for the info above, unfortunately I am still falling into "error" with status of 200.  :(

Comment: are you returning something ? Then it shoudn't fail

Comment: and yes you are not doing any sanitization user input, It will create XSS problems, which is probably top in web security OWASP list.

Comment: Yes, I tried returning a 1, unfortunately it still goes into the error portion, which still is extremely confusing to me.  I think I may just have to handle the status 200 and treat it like a success even though PHP seems to think it's an error...that just seems to be bad form though.  I am also going to be researching the injection attacks to prevent those, thats for the info!